# set layout in routes into the scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, routes, scope

I have admin controller and I want to set layout for '/admin' path.

I try like:

```
scope '/admin' do
  layout 'admin' # did't work
  get '/' => 'admin#index', as: 'admin'
  resources :posts, as: 'admin_posts'
end
```

I can set layout in AdminController like:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
end
```

but is a bad way because rationally use some layout for all controllers who call from '/admin' path

How I can do it?

Comment: can you please explain little more what exactly you want to do? Do you want to use admin layout in every controller under admin scope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant set layout directly in your routes.rb

I think what you do is the right way

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
end
```

Now you will use AdminController to generate other controllers in admin scope

```
class UsersController < AdminController
end
```

or if in a namespace

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
end
```

Thats what i do, if i did understand your question.

Comment: I will use folders into controllers folder and use class Admin::UsersController < AdminController. Thank you!